# Null Value when passing JSON data from POSTMAN to Controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, post

I'm trying to pass a list of objects to a controller using Postman

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("save")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveConfigurationConstants([FromBody] List<ConfigurationConstant> configurationConstants)
```

This is the class for the object

```
 public class ConfigurationConstant
    {
        public ConfigurationConstant();

        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the Postman Request.Here options `raw` and `JSON` are set.But when putting breakpoint in controller null is received.
[image]

Comment: Your code expects an array and you're posting an object.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo

Comment: Your options are: define the parent object with an array property of `ConfigurationConstant` named "configurationConstants" and deserialize to a single one of these, or remove the fluff around your array in your JSON.

Comment: You want the JSON to look something like this: `[{"Key":"mykey","Value":"8"}]`.

Comment: @MartinCostello I created a wrapper to wrap the list and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted that to not error you would do something like this instead in your models.

```
public class ConfigurationConstant
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
public class ConfigurationConstants
{
    public List<ConfigurationConstant> configurationConstants { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("save")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveConfigurationConstants([FromBody] ConfigurationConstants configurationConstants)
```